Adding additional search location
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddControllersWithViews();
    services.AddRazorPages();
    services.AddDbContext<ProductDbContext>
    (opts =>
    {
        opts.UseSqlServer(Configuration["ConnectionStrings:AppDataConnection"]);
    });
    services.AddHttpsRedirection(opts =>
    {
        opts.HttpsPort = 44350;

    });      
    services.Configure<RazorViewEngineOptions>(opts=> {
        opts.PageViewLocationFormats.Clear();

       opts.PageViewLocationFormats.Add("/Pages/Shared/Layouts/{0}"     +  RazorViewEngine.ViewExtension);              
    });
}

I am configuring the RazorViewEngineOptions in the ConfigureServices method in Startup to add additional entries to the PageViewLocationFormats collection.
The program still searches only the default locations.
I cleared the list PageViewLocationFormats list
opts.PageViewLocationFormats.Clear();

but the program still searches only the default locations and shows error:

An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
InvalidOperationException: The layout view '_Layout' could not be located. The following locations were searched:
/Views/Home/_Layout.cshtml
/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml
/Pages/Shared/_Layout.cshtml

Why is this not working? I am sure I did the same thing in previous versions and it used to work...

Could you pls let us know the .net version you are using now? According to the document, RazorViewEngineOptions.PageViewLocationFormats should support asp.net core 2.0, 2.1, 2.2, 3.0, 3.1, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0, 9.0 Preview

I had a test in my side with a .net 8 razor web app and it worked well. I moved the default layout.cshtml to /Pages/Shared/Layouts/layout.cshtml, without the configuartion the app would throw exception, but adding the configuration will make everything work.

I am using asp.net core 5.0 .I didn't understand what does without the configuration meaning? Can you pls specify

According to your description, you are trying to move the _Layout.cshtml file from /Pages/Shared/_Layout.cshtml to /Pages/Shared/Layouts/_Layout.cshtml, but the default RazorViewEngine will search for views from /Views/Home , /Views/Shared, /Pages/Shared/ folder, so that you have to add such configuration to ask the RazorViewEngine to search for the views from specifc folder.

Can you pls specify the code to add such configuration to ask RazorViewEngine to search for views from specific folder

I test with a .net 8 razor web app and I just use your codes. builder.Services.Configure<RazorViewEngineOptions>(opts => {opts.PageViewLocationFormats.Add("/Pages/Shared/Layouts/{0}" +RazorViewEngine.ViewExtension);});  I don't have .net 5 SDK in my machine. Could yuo pls try in a long-time support .net version? .Net 5 is end-of-life.
